# Using the same entity for different use cases

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, entity

Suppose I have a `User` entity with `name` and `age` attributes. A `User` can own `Box`es. A `Box` has the `name` and `color` attributes. Business rules dictate that one `User` can own at most 5 boxes. So, in this case, the `User` can be the aggregate root and whenever a new `Box` is bought by a `User`, I can do

```
class User {
  private boxes: Box[];
  private MAX_BOXES = 5;

  // snip

  addBox(Box box) {
    if (this.boxes.count > MAX_BOXES) {
      throw new BoxLimitException();
    }

    this.boxes.add(box);
  }
}
```

However, when I want to edit one `Box`'s (or a `User`, for that matter) attributes, the box limit business rule is no longer needed so I should be able to just modify it directly, without going through the aggregate, i.e.:

```
box->paint(GREEN);
```

But, according to what I've read on DDD, you're not supposed to do that, since you're breaking the bounded context of the aggregate root. Should I have different `Box` entities depending on the use case? Specially since a `Box` might have its own business rules independent of those of a `User` aggregate.

---

I already asked a [similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/390955/modify-a-property-of-an-aggregates-entity), but it got no answers, so I tried with this new, simpler example, to  better explain my doubts.

Comment: It's difficult to compose a satisfying answer in this case because the *behavior* of a system is what should inform the design. Given the behavior above there is no reason a `User` needs a `Box` collection at all! It could (and I'd argue should) be modeled such that the `User` only needs a `private numberOfBoxes: int` property to enforce our single invariant. In this way we can avoid the "problem" you lay out entirely.

Comment: I see, and agree with the 'behaviour modeling' approach. With the `numberOfBoxes` property you suggest, how would I go about adding a Box to the user? In my service I'd have to load the repository for both the User and the Box, and doing the invariant check on the User aggregate, and afterwards persist the Box aggregate. Is that right? I know better than following methodologies blindly rather than pragmatically, but DDD seems *so* rigid that I have these kind of doubts pretty much every time I have to model anything.

Comment: Correct. I'll compose an example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common pattern used to separate a group of entities given invariants that span between them is to break down the use-case into a series of steps and employ value objects/factory methods as a means of communication.

I am going to extend your example to help illustrate what I mean. Let us introduce a new concept, `Container`, to which `Box`s are added (instead of `User`), and one more invariant: A `Box` can only be added to a `Container` by a `User` that has completed payment. Given our two invariants, how can we model this in a way to keep `Container`, `Box` and `User` as separate entities?

```
class User
{   
    private userId: int;
    private hasCompletedPayment: bool;

    public AddBoxIntent addBox(string content)
    {
        if (!this.hasCompletedPayment) {
            throw new UserCannotAddBoxException();
        }

        return new AddBoxIntent(this.userId, content);
    }
}

// value object
class AddBoxIntent
{
    public readonly userId: int;
    public readonly content: string;
}


class Container
{
    private containerId: int;
    private numberOfBoxes: int;
    private MAX_BOXES = 5;

    public Box addBox(AddBoxIntent intent) 
    {
        if (this.numberOfBoxes >= this.MAX_BOXES) {
            throw new BoxLimitException();
        }

        this.numberOfBoxes++;

        return new Box(this.containerId, intent.userId, intent.content);
   }
}

// Box not shown
```

We can see above that `User.addBox` is a factory method used to obtain *permission* to add a `Box` to any `Container` at some later point in time (guarding our payment invariant), and `Container.addBox` is a factory method used to produce a new `Box` related to our `User` and `Container`.

A use-case may then look like:

```
// within our service

user = users.find(cmd.userId);

container = containers.find(cmd.containerId);

intent = user.addBox(cmd.content); // may throw

box = container.addBox(intent); // may throw

boxes.save(box);
```

In this way we are allowing all three of our entities to be loaded/changed independently of one another should be want to perform modifications in other ways.

Comment: I love this. In all my research I'd never read about the Intent patter applied in DDD. It's so clean! Thanks so much.